# Добавить элемент <span> к li, если li содержит подменю

Tags: javascript

Как добавить (к примеру span) к элементу li если есть подпункты меню?

Получить что то вроде:

ONE >

ONE-1

ONE-2

Мне нужно туда стрелку добавить через css. Так будет понятно что пункт меню с подпунктами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// берём все li у которых есть подменю
let inner = document.querySelectorAll('li ul');

inner.forEach(el => {
  // для каждого создаём эл-т span
  let arrow = document.createElement('span');
  // добавляем созданному span класс arrow, который задаёт вид стрелки вправо
  arrow.classList.add('arrow');
  // добавляем созданный span ("стрелку") перед вложенным меню
  el.parentElement.insertBefore(arrow, el);
});
```

```css
.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2
    <ul>
      <li>2-1</li>
      <li>2-2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5
    <ul>
      <li>5-1</li>
      <li>5-2</li>
      <li>5-3</li>
      <li>5-4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Именно так как мне нужно работает!

Comment: @Vlad_is_LavКиевский Вы можете отметить данный ответ как принятый (зелёная галочка слева), раз он решил вашу задачу. Вы получите +2, а отвечающий +15. Также вы можете голосовать за (стрелочка вверх) данный ответ, если он был вам полезен.